# iOS - Changing transform invalidates changes in center

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

Lets say I have a view A as a subview of view B, when I change the transform and center property of the view A, the center value is ignored.

Here is my code, I subclassed a UIView:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    CGPoint location = [touches.anyObject locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = location;
}
```

What does this happen and how can I solve it?

Btw, I did check, the self.center property is changing, it is just that the actual view is not using it. Also, even if I don't change back the de Identity transform, the first time it changes the transform is enough to invalidate the center property for this first method call.

I know it seems a dumb question (why would I want to change the transform back and forth), but I have some real code that ends up doing that, so if this works my real code will work too.

Thank you.

Comment: It have tested and it works fine in my simulator. Are you sure that you have set `self.transfrom` back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` before setting its center property?

Comment: It is said that "If this property(transfrom) is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property (so is the center property) is undefined and therefore should be ignored."

Comment: I just found out that when I manually create the custom view (with alloc, init) instead of using the interface builder, it works.
Any idea why the layout constraints are screwing it up?

Comment: I also found out that if I use self.layer.transform instead of self.transform, it works. Any idea why?